# ERROR IN Firebase OTP Auth Using Bloc in flutter

Tags: android, flutter

This is bloc code

```
 void _verifyPhoneNumber(
  LoginInSubmittedEvent event, Emitter<SignInState> emit) async {
String phone = "+91${event.phoneNumber}";
try {
  emit(SignInLoadingState());
  await firebaseAuth.verifyPhoneNumber(
    phoneNumber: phone,
    verificationCompleted: (PhoneAuthCredential credential) async {
      emit(SignInCompletedState(credential));
    },
    verificationFailed: (FirebaseAuthException e) async {
      emit(SignInErrorState(e.toString()));
    },
    codeSent: (String verificationId, int? resendToken) async {
      emit(SignInValidateState(verificationId, resendToken));
    },
    codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: (String verificationId) async {
      emit(SignInTimeoutState(verificationId));
    },
  );
} catch (e) {
  emit(SignInErrorState(e.toString()));
}
```

}

Getting Updating State using Bloc here on button click calling the event add(LoginInSubmittedEvent() and checking all states here

```
 child: TextButton(
                                  onPressed: () {
                                    const phoneNumber = '3453453252';

                                    //BLOC TESST
                                    BlocProvider.of<SignInBloc>(context)
                                        .add(LoginInSubmittedEvent(
                                            phoneNumber));
                                    if (state is SignInInitialState) {
                                      debugPrint('Initial State');
                                    } else if (state
                                        is SignInLoadingState) {
                                      debugPrint('Loading State');
                                    } else if (state is SignInErrorState) {
                                      Text(state.errorMessage);
                                    } else if (state
                                        is SignInValidateState) {
                                      debugPrint('OTP SENT State');
                                    } else if (state
                                        is SignInTimeoutState) {
                                      debugPrint('TimeOut State');
                                    }
                                  },
                                  child: Text(
                                    'Get Otp',
                                    style:
                                        AppTextStyles.backNextBtnTextStyle,
                                  ),
                                ),
```

Getting ERROR Is

```
  **BAD** on<Event>((event, emit) {  future.whenComplete(() => emit(...)); });:  **GOOD** on<Event>((event, emit) async {
await future.whenComplete(() => emit(...)); }); use emit.isDone after asynchronous operations before calling emit() to ensure the event handler has not completed.
```